# AngularJS - directive with templateUrl function refresh/redraw/update

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angularJS directive, which has it's templateUrl property set to a function, that determines which template to use based on a service function. When the service finishes a certain job (which is triggered by an event inside the directive too), it triggers a callback, which modifies the directive's scope, and should call a "redraw" of the directive. And by redraw, I mean call the templateUrl function, and update the template properly based on new values inside the service. I have no idea how to call this redraw/update, and google was no use with my problem.

```
application.directive('loginform', ['authorization', function(auth) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: function(element, attributes)
        {
            if(auth.token() != "")
            {
                return "/client/templates/loginForm_disabled.html";
            }
            else
            {
                return "/client/templates/loginForm_enabled.html";
            }
        },    

        link: function($scope, element, attributes) {
            $scope.username = "";
            $scope.password = "";
            $scope.message = "";

            //this function is called on a button press.
            $scope.login = function() {
                auth.login($scope.username, $scope.password, function (success) {
                    if(!success)
                    {
                        $scope.message = "Login was unsuccessful";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.message = "";
                    }
                    //call a redraw/update of the template
                });
            }
    }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Why can't you simply use ng-if or ng-show directive inside the template? it could be something like: `<div ng-if="auth.token">disabled form</div>`. Then Angular take care of it.

Comment: ng-if creates a child scope. I would like to avoid that, if possible. If there is no good solution with templateUrl updating, then I'll use ng-ifs.

Answer (score 0):

try using $scope.$apply()

the details of this questions might help.

[How to modify scope from within a directive in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561632/how-to-modify-scope-from-within-a-directive-in-angularjs)