# AngularJS directive action requires scope digest, why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple button directive that notifies the controller when the button is clicked. However I do not understand why I need to add $scope.$digest() in order for the action to update the scope. See code:

```js
var myModule = angular.module("myModule", []);

myModule.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      action: "&"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("click", function() {
        scope.action();
      });
    }
  };
});

myModule.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.divShow = false;
  $scope.buttonClick = function() {
    $scope.divShow = !$scope.divShow;
    // why is this needed?
    $scope.$digest();
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <button my-directive action="buttonClick()">Click</button>
    <div ng-show="divShow">
      Div is shown
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigg75/xy0bwd73/8/)

Comment: Because a DOM event (`element.bind()`) doesn't automatically trigger a digest cycle.

Comment: This is true. If I were using ng-click then I wouldn't need to worry about calling digest since it's called automatically. Instead I'm handing the event handler via click and therefore responsible to run the digest cycle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not run a digest cycle yourself (see [AngularJS docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)) instead, you can run the function in a **scope.$evalAsync / scope.$apply / $timeout (*)** callback, as the `scope.action()` code is executed "outside" of angular (it is in a normal JS handler) :

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("click", function() {
        scope.$evalAsync(function(){
            scope.action();
        });
    });
}
```

**(*) Which one is "best" to use is outside the scope of this answer : **

- [AngularJS : Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply)
- [How to modify scope from within a directive in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561632/how-to-modify-scope-from-within-a-directive-in-angularjs)
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm