# Angular directive which resizes elements automatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a directive which makes elements resize automatically according to percents of window. But there are still problems I can't solve.

Here are the files:

autoresize.js:

```
angular.module('autoresize', [])

    .directive('autoresize', function() { return {

        scope:{theId:'@id', theClass:'@class', wFactor:'@w', hFactor:'@h'},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.onResize = function() {
                if(scope.hFactor != 'w')
                {
                    scope.height = Math.floor($(window).innerHeight()*scope.hFactor);
                }
                if(scope.wFactor != 'h')
                {
                    scope.width = Math.floor($(window).innerWidth()*scope.wFactor);
                }
                if(scope.hFactor == 'w')
                {
                    scope.height = scope.width;
                }
                if(scope.wFactor == 'h')
                {
                    scope.width = scope.height;
                }

                $(elem).outerHeight(scope.height);
                $(elem).outerWidth(scope.width);
            }
            scope.onResize();

            angular.element($(window)).bind('resize', function() {
                scope.onResize();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

test.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#left, #right
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#left
{
    background: #101010;
}

#right
{
    background: #777777;
}

#bottom
{
    background: #AAAAAA;
}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="left" autoresize w="0.5" h="0.8"></div><div id="right" autoresize w="0.5" h="0.8"></div>
                <div id="bottom" autoresize w="1" h="0.2">{{width}}</div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script src="vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

        <script src="autoresize.js"></script>
        <script>
angular.module('testApp', ['autoresize'])

    .controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http) {



});
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The first problem is that when I open the webapp, the sizes don't init correctly: I must resize the window to get it work. Why doesn't the line `scope.onResize()` in the link function init everything correctly?

The second problem is that the scope variables "width" and "height" are not accessible in the element: in the example below, there isn't anything in the div "bottom". How do you get them accessible?

(Here you could think that CSS would be sufficient, however actually my app is a bit more complicated that the example below and CSS isn't sufficient)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For the second problem, the isolated scope was the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ad 1)**
The `scope.onResize()` does not work, because when the `link` function on a directive is called, the DOM element handled by that directive is not yet rendered (it will be, once the directive is done processing). Try to wrap that call in `$timeout()`, like this:

```
$timeout(function() { scope.onResize(); });
```

This will cause calling `scope.onResize()` during the *next tick*, which is after the directive finishes processing.

**Ad 2)**
See [this question, on how to modify scope from within a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561632/how-to-modify-scope-from-within-a-directive-in-angularjs).

Comment: 1) With the timeout function, it's exactly the same: it resizes elements but not with the appropriate width/height.

2) I think it's not the same: I need to access the scope created by my directive, not the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need call you `scope.onResize();` method from load event of element, That would be efficient to initial kick off for setting css of elements

Add below method in directive & remove direct call of `scope.onResize();` from link function

**Code**

```
 element.on('load', function() {
     scope.onResize();
 });
```

Comment: Adding this code in the link function doesn't make it work better. Where do you suggest I must add it?

Comment: @Niolak link function is the only better place for it..don't remove any code..add this extra fucntion]