# Proper method to handle Angular scope instead of $parent.$parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been reading a few articles, and haven't found the example that solves my issue.

My understanding is that:

1. `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` create isolate scopes.
2. Using `$parent.someProperty` is bad.
3. Using `$parent.$parent.someProperty` would be an abomination.

So, with the given template markup, how can I properly bind the the controller *so that the controller property updates*?

**Markup:**
(note the nested `ng-if` and `ng-repeat`, creating a sort of `$parent.$parent` situation)

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-if="showOnCondition">
    <label ng-repeat="item in repeatingItems">
      {{item}}
      <setting item="item" />
    </label>
  </div>
  {{checkSetting()}}
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    someProperty: '',
    anotherProperty: 'Hello'
  }

  $scope.repeatingItems = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
  ];

  $scope.showOnCondition = true;

  $scope.checkSetting = function() {
    // When calling checkSettings(), I would like to access the value of someProperty here
    return $scope.settings;
  }
});

myApp.directive('setting', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^myCtrl',
    // HOW DO I SOLVE THIS?
    // $parent.$parent is bad.
    template: '<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.$parent.settings.someProperty" name="mySetting" value="{{item}}" />',
    scope: {
      settings: '=',
      item: '='
    }
  };
});
```

Given the above example, how to I properly construct the directive and / or markup in order to access `settings.someProperty` in the controller? Or is there something entirely different I need to be doing?

**Clarification**
There seems to be some confusion around what I'm trying to do.  The `someProperty` is available in the directive - that is working fine.  Please note I'm trying to *assign values* to the controller's `someProperty` property from *within* the directive (using ng-model)

**Update**
I've revised the code above to known, working code, plus added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XyUGE/473/).
Note that it *works*, but it uses `$parent.$parent` in the template.  This is the problem I need to understand how to solve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672709/how-to-require-a-controller-in-an-angularjs-directive

Comment: Take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/XyUGE/1/) Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, that's a simple example that doesn't contain the nested isolate scopes.

Comment: First of all, scopes are not isolated so you can use scope inheritance here. Then controllerAs approach will always work in such cases.

Comment: @dfsq - the child scopes / directive aren't "talking" to the controller.  As far as "controllerAs" approach, thanks, but I have no idea what that means!  I appreciate the help, but you're speaking in fairly big generalities, and I'm looking for some specific(s) to help get my head wrapped around this.

Comment: I don't think this is the recommended approach but I've used the compile method of the directive to go up the $parent chain till I find it and then preprocessed the template in the past.

Comment: While not what you are looking for, this is an interesting alternate way to arrange a $parent call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561632/how-to-modify-scope-from-within-a-directive-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass settings through to the directive, which I think is the simplest / most direct / cleanest way to do this.

Angular properly evaluates `settings` as `MyCtrl.settings`, then passes it through to the isolate scope of the `setting` directive.  Inside the directive, you have two-way binding on `settings`, so you can update settings from there.

Modifying your example, pass in `settings` into the directive in the **Markup**:

`<setting settings="settings" item="item" />`

Then in the **JavaScript**, swap out this for the template:

`template: '<input type="radio" ng-model="settings.someProperty" ng-value="item" name="mySetting" />',`

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rm1338/7fxh5925/4/).

Comment: Good point, @cale_b, added relevant code bits, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I'm rewriting my answer completely, based on your fiddle and a simpler two-way data-binding approach. Note to future readers that the first couple of comments are no longer relevant to this updated answer.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-if="showOnCondition">
    <label ng-repeat="item in repeatingItems">
      {{item}}
      <setting test="settings.someProperty" item="item" />
    </label>
  </div>
  {{checkSetting()}}
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    someProperty: true,
    anotherProperty: 'Hello'
  }

  $scope.repeatingItems = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
  ];

  $scope.showOnCondition = true;

  $scope.checkSetting = function() {
    // When calling checkSettings(), I would like to access the value of someProperty here
    return $scope.settings;
  }
});

myApp.directive('setting', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
    template: '<input type="radio" ng-model="test" name="mySetting" value="{{item}}" />',
    scope: {
      test: '=',
      item: '='
    }
  };
});
```

This provides two-way data-binding between the parent controller property and the directive. With this approach, you would pass in each individual parent scope property to an attribute, and bind it in your isolate scope.

Comment: @cale_b - are you specifically limited to Angular 1.1.5 like you used in the fiddle?

Comment: No, that was an oversight.  I'm actually using Angular 1.4.7

Comment: @cale_b - take a look at this now.

Answer (score 0):

One option when hierarchical relationships and data passing gets complicated is to decouple the parent/child relationships and just have a service to share the data.

I've seen some great explanations on this, for example [passing state via services](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/passing-state-via-services), with [sample code](https://github.com/rclayton/NG-Communicate-Ctrls/blob/master/service/index.html).  You could also adapt this idea for use with a generic cache service like Angular's [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) or, more sophisticated, this library: [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache).

Comment: I've heard of this concept, but it seems like a lot of overhead just to get an input's value on a template into the parent controller.  I keep thinking there must be a simpler way?

Comment: You're right - I finally wrapped my head around it and provided a simpler answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35025628/3232832, but will probably leave this in place as a data point for decoupled services.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a param 'someproperty' to pass into the settings directive = like so:

```
myApp.directive('setting', function() {
   return {
   restrict: 'E',
   template: '<input type="radio" ng-model="myProperty" 
   value="{{item}}" />',
   scope: {
      settings: '=',
      item: '=',
      myProperty: '='
   }
  };
});
```

And in your markup:

```
<label ng-repeat="item in repeatingItems">
  {{item}}
  <setting item="item" myProperty="settings.someProperty" />
</label>
```

Comment: The myProperty param is  2 way data binding, right?  So the new parm "myProperty=setting.someProperty" is bound to the controller $scope.settings.  If the child directive makes changes to it, the controller will see those changes.  And also In the template input element,  the param is passed to ng-model.