# Change scope variables between controller and directive

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

As the title says am trying to change scope variable from directive and from my controller. But it cannot change the value from controller/directive, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJ7FQ/242/)

If you click `Change` button it will change both scope variables from controller.

Then when clicking `changed from controller` button (which is now the directive), it will change `drop` variable but not the `select` variable and `Change` button cannot change the variable again.

> I have also tried to pass the variable as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17561741/1129995) but with no
>   success.

Directive :

```
 app.directive("drop", [function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    restrict: 'A',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      return element.bind('click', function(e) {
        scope.drop = "changed to drop";
        scope.select = "changed to select";
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

controller:

```
function myController($scope) {
  $scope.drop = "Initial value";
  $scope.select = "Initial Value";
  $scope.selection = function() {
    $scope.drop = "changed from controller";
    $scope.select = "changed from controller";
  };
}
```

**Edit:**

More testing shows that when changing the scope variable in directive, then controller cannot change it anymore..

Comment: You use a `scope: true`, which will create a child scope that prototypically inherits from the controller scope. Controller scope changes will reflect in the child scope, but not the other way around

Comment: @devqon yes removing scope:true resolves it but in my local project I am mirroring exactly what is in jsfiddle it wont work once the directive event is clicked...

Answer (score 1):

remove the directive's `scope` attribute value, it gives the directive it's own scope

Comment: +1 It does resolve it for jsfiddle sample..In my local machine I am mirroring exactly what is in jsfiddle it wont work once the directive event is clicked.

Comment: I am using requirejs not sure if that effects it in anyway